# How to stop an Angular 2 component initialization and navigate to a default (safe) route

Tags: angular

I have a situation where as a `Component` is initializing the component detects that the application is not in the proper state for the component to correctly load/operate. The component's `ngOnInit` method tries to `navigate()` to a safe page to prevent utter failure due to an `undefined` object's member being accessed within the template.

```
ngOnInit() {
  // when no scenario has been passed to the component:
  // try to get the active one from the application context via the scenario service

  if (null == this.scenario) {

    this.scenario = this.scenarioService.activeScenario;

    // when there's no current scenario set in the application context:
    // try to get one from the scenario service in the active period

    if (null == this.scenario) { 

      this.scenario = this.scenarioService.getScenariosByYear(this.settingsService.activePeriod)[0];

      // when there's no scenarios defined in the active period:
      // navigate to the the scenario manager component so the user can create one

      if (null == this.scenario) {

        this.router.navigate(['/scenario']); // <==== this doesn't seem to fire

      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Question 1** : Why doesn't the `this.router.navigate(['/scenario']);` call work (interrupt the component lifecycle)?

**Question 2** : Generically, is there a way to stop the component lifecycle during initialization to permit preemptive navigation to a safe place?

Comment: Works fine for me https://plnkr.co/edit/fjHkRLRDzVyw1U1smw48?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a guard. Guards can be used to prevent navigation to a route, or you can use them to intercept and redirect like you want in this case. See https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Answer (score 0):

At present it seems that Angular 2 does not provide a mechanism for the application to interrupt (stop) the component lifecycle and the rendering of the component template (and child components / templates).

A colleague recommended placing conditional processing / rendering logic on all properties within my parent component and all of the related child component properties to prevent erroneous access to `undefined` objects within my components. This approach surely would work, but seemed rather tedious to set up and even more painful to maintain, so I decided to tackle the problem at a slightly higher level...

Ultimately, my approach was to use a wrapping `<div *ngIf="valid"></div>` element around my parent component's template and place each of the subordinate child component templates within their own wrapping `<div *ngIf="valid"></div>` element. Doing this gave me the ability to stop the templates from rendering in the case of `undefined` objects. I then created a service to which the child components listen and for the parent component to signal when a valid instantiation of the parent component has occurred (e.g. no `undefined` objects exist).

If anyone might have a better suggestion for how to deal with this type of situation, please let me know.